# android mapview balloons - always show all ballons

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-overlay

I am using the android [mapview balloons open source](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons)

How can i tweak it so it will always show ALL the balloons on the overlay ?
**Update:**
What i want to achieve is having a list of overlays on the map, each containing the bubble on top of it, with the address of that overlay .
I want ALL the icons (and their balloons) to be visible ALL THE TIME, regardless of a tap on a specific item .
this way, the addresses are always visible and you don't have to tap on an item to see its address balloon .

Comment: Only the ballons that are placed one the map visible area can be displayed. Can you be more specific on exactly what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you have a class that extends BalloonItemizedOverlay.

You can programatically call ***onTap( int indexOfOverlay )*** to make the ballon pop up.

If you don't have any functionality associated with each of the ballons, you can override the onTap method to iterate over the list of overlay items and call onTap for each of them, to display all the ballons at once. You can then call this method when adding the BalloonItemizedOverlay to the map view overlays.

Comment: this is a hack, but i have no other appropriate solution so your answer is accepted. thanks !

Comment: hi @programmer, i am facing the same problem. i am a java and android new bee. can you share the code for where all the ballons get populated on activity load. I am unable to understand Robert is suggesting.

Comment: just see mapview-balloons-main project (the example project attached to the mapview balloons library). they do it there ..

Comment: @Robert Estivill - calling onTap for all of the balloons causes only the last one on the list to be shown. your solution didn't work ..

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
overlay.setShowDisclosure(true);
overlay.setSnapToCenter(true);
```

Comment: i'll try it tomorrow. if this works your answer will be accepted .. thank you!